# How to remove Tax of Associated Products of Group Product in Cart and Checkout Page in Magento2?

Tags: tax, grouped-products, taxes, tax-calculation

How to remove Tax of Associated Products of Group Product in Cart and Checkout Page in Magento2?

**Ex:** Group Product **$1000** (Set Custom Price using Observer)

- **Product A :** $500
- **Product B :** $500
- **Tax Rate Set :** 15%

So Subtotal becomes **$1150** (**$150** As a Tax).

I want to make Subtotal **$1000**(Only In Group Product).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in two ways.

1. Use the price and the tax setting of the simple
2. Hook into one of the add to cart events and add only the simple.
   Then build an observer that redirects from the simple to the
   configurable